# ReWriteRule to extract and rewrite date

Tags: regex, date, mod-rewrite

Can someone please help me understand how I can write a ReWriteRule in `.htaccess` file to take a `dmmmyyyy` string format and forward it to `yyyy-mm-dd.html`?

So for example, `mydomain.com/7nov2014` should be redirected to `mydomain.com/path/to/content/2014-11-07.html`

Also if the day is two digit it should still work for example, `mydomain.com/17nov2014` should go to `mydoamin.com/path/to/content/2014-11-17.html`

So if day passed is 1 digit, append 0, otherwise, use as is.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to setup a table for the conversion.

Here we're first checking for any double digit day of the month `([0-9]{2})`. If that fails, then we look at single digits `([0-9]{1})`, in that order to save time and overhead since there are more double-digit days in a month than single digit days. This allows us to append a `0` zero character in front of the single day digit. We store this in the group 1 variable via the parenthesis.

Next we convert the 3-digit month code to the month number; since we're not going to keep the original we just do a clean replacement.

Finally we capture the 4-digit year in group `2([0-9]{4})`.

This is followed by a possible trailing slash character `/?` since the original naming convention looks like a folder.

Unfortunately `.htaccess` files aren't exactly like a programming language, but really more of a configuration file so there is  no function for date recognition and conversion like there are in high level languages:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jan([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-01-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})feb([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-02-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})mar([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-03-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})apr([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-04-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})may([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-05-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jun([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-06-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jul([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-07-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})aug([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-08-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})sep([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-09-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})oct([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-10-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})nov([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-11-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})dec([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-12-$1

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jan([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-01-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})feb([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-02-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})mar([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-03-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})apr([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-04-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})may([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-05-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jun([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-06-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jul([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-07-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})aug([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-08-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})sep([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-09-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})oct([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-10-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})nov([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-11-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})dec([0-9]{4})/?$ path/to/content/$2-12-0$1
```

Also according to [the manual for rewrite_rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), you should be able to use the RewriteBase to your advantage to alleviate all of the duplicate paths in the file as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/to/content/

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jan([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-01-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})feb([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-02-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})mar([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-03-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})apr([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-04-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})may([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-05-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jun([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-06-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})jul([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-07-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})aug([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-08-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})sep([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-09-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})oct([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-10-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})nov([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-11-$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{2})dec([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-12-$1

RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jan([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-01-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})feb([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-02-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})mar([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-03-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})apr([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-04-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})may([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-05-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jun([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-06-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})jul([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-07-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})aug([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-08-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})sep([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-09-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})oct([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-10-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})nov([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-11-0$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1})dec([0-9]{4})/?$ $2-12-0$1
```

You could look for single digits first, but the system would go through all single digits for every possible conversion. You could make this significantly more complicated with look arounds and look-up tables for the conversion, but this is the simplest straight-forward approach at a glance.